# how to use this definition in c# with dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
GROUP["10"]["MATH"] = 30;
GROUP["11"]["MATH"] = 40;
GROUP["9"]["CHEM"] = 50;
...
```

Can u tell me how to use it with dictionaries. How to define a dictionary for this example?

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what problem you're actually trying to solve? This code already looks a bit ugly.

Comment: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>>
```

The first [] returns a dictionary, and the second [] operates on that dictionary and returns an int

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
```

Use:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
Dictionary<string, int> inner = new Dictionary<string, int>();
inner.Add("MATH", 30);
dic.Add("10", inner);

...
```

Access

```
dic["10"]["MATH"]
```

Answer (score 4):

use this one ......

```
 Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>>
```

pls go through this link for more info ....On dictionaries,if you are new to dictionaries..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>` but you may better defining a class/ custom collection to better represent this, it depends on what your use case is.

An example of `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>
           {
               { new Tuple<string,string>("10", "MATH"), 30 },
               { new Tuple<string,string>("11", "MATH"), 40 },
               { new Tuple<string,string>("9", "CHEM"), 50 }
           };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**: Use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`.

```
Dictionary<string, int> group10 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
group10.Add("MATH", 30);
Dictionary<string, int> group11 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
group10.Add("MATH", 40);
Dictionary<string, int> group9 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
group10.Add("CHEM", 50);
var group = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
group.Add("10", group10);
group.Add("11", group11);
group.Add("9", group9);

int v1 = group["10"]["MATH"]; // v1 = 30
int v2 = group["11"]["MATH"]; // v2 = 40
int v3 = group["9"]["CHEM"]; // v3 = 50
```

**Option 2**: Or create a compound key for the dictionary that overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, or you could use `Tuple`.

```
var group = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>();
group.Add(Tuple.Create("10", "MATH"), 30);
group.Add(Tuple.Create("11", "MATH"), 40);
group.Add(Tuple.Create("9", "CHEM"), 50);

int v1 = group[Tuple.Create("10", "MATH")]; // v1 = 30
int v2 = group[Tuple.Create("11", "MATH")]; // v2 = 40
int v3 = group[Tuple.Create("9", "CHEM")]; // v3 = 50
```

If using Option 1 you must remember to create the second level `Dictionary<string, int>`, before adding the integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string><int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string><int>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create your own dictionary:

```
public class GroupDict
{
    const string Separator = ";";

    Dictionary<string, int> _internalDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void Add(string key1, string key2, int value)
    {
        _internalDict.Add(key1 + Separator + key2, value);
    }

    public int this[string key1, string key2]
    {
        get { return _internalDict[key1 + Separator + key2]; }
        set { _internalDict[key1 + Separator + key2] = value; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _internalDict.Count; }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
GroupDict groups = new GroupDict();
groups.Add("10", "MATH", 30);
// OR
groups["10", "MATH"] = 30;

Console.WriteLine(groups["10", "MATH"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you can't create a Multi-Key Dictionary in C#.

You will need your own struct for that.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit. Please, try to stick to proper English. E.g.: `you` rather than `u`.